# Python and PHP not playing ball, only very small part is being parsed

Tags: php, python, html, ssh

So I'm currently having a Python script scan for WiFi networks and print out the results:

```
from subprocess import check_output
scanoutput = check_output(["iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"])
print '<select name="ssid">'
for line in scanoutput.split("\n"):
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("ESSID:"):
                line=line[7:-1]
                print '<option value="' + line + '">' + line + </option>'
print "</select>"
```

It looks well when I try it in SSH:

```
<select name="ssid">
<option value="easybell DSL">easybell DSL</option>
<option value="FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360 SL_EXT">FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360 SL_EXT</option>
<option value="WLAN-519293">WLAN-519293</option>
<option value="NoTrespassing">NoTrespassing</option>
<option value="Cinque">Cinque</option>
<option value="EasyBox-738461">EasyBox-738461</option>
<option value="FRITZ!Box WLAN 3270">FRITZ!Box WLAN 3270</option>
</select>
```

which is then used by PHP:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/process.py" method="get">
<?php $output=shell_exec("/usr/bin/python cgi-bin/wifi-scan.py"); print_r($output);?>
<input type="password" value="password" name="psk" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}">
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(){shell_exec("process.py")}" value="Connect" ></div>
</form>
```

Sadly however, when I go on the website, it only shows one option in the dropbox menu. In my frustration I ran the Python code through SSH to see if it was working and what could be the issue. When I refreshed the website directly after, all the options showed up.

This seems to be persistant.

To be able to get a full list, I first need to run it through SSH before I can refresh the site and see a full list. This will last up to roughly 10 secondes, after which only the first option shows up again and manual intervention is needed.

What could be the problem here? I'm at my wits end here!

Thanks!!

Comment: In my troubleshooting mode, I was thinking perhaps it was an apache2 error, so I've installed lighttpd instead, this shows the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script, which is exectured by PHP over lighttpd is run as www-data. The command iwlist requires root privileges. If it is performed by a user who does not have root privileges (www-data), it returns only the information referring to the wifi where you are connected, which is why I thought it was working but only outputting one line instead of all of them.

Of course, to minimize the risk for exploits on the system I am not launching lighttpd as root, nor am I giving www-data root privileges.

Instead, have edited my sudoers file to accept to have only this specific python script to be run as sudo by doing:

```
sudo visudo
```

and adding this line:

```
www-data ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/var/www/html/cgi-bin/wifi-scan.py
```